# How do I save a Value to a variable using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright

Hi im trying to automatically solve captchas using 2captcha and puppeteer and I'm having trouble saving the value of the data-sitekey to a variable I've never used javascript or puppeteer before so any pointers would be helpful

What I'm Trying to get

```
<div id="g-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfjzmQUAAAAAJxTOcx3vYq3hroeYczGfDPU-NlX"></div>
```

What I've Tried

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return result.querySelectorAll('#g-recaptcha');
  })
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `result.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.querySelectorAll`. It should be:

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelectorAll('#g-recaptcha');
})
console.log(result.dataset.sitekey);
```

Or better yet do:

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.getElementById('g-recaptcha').getAttribute('data-sitekey');
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That Worked Perfectly Thanks So much

Comment: For me, it returns an object result with `result[0]` being `{}`. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco the answer is selected by the questioner so it must've been correct at the time. don't know if pupeeteer changed now so you can confirm if it's correct or not. i haven't tried using it for a long time now.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 someone answered me on [github](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9286) about this. all i got is that is not possible for me, lol